# Single responsibility in React component

Tags: reactjs, single-responsibility-principle

I was learning Single responsibility principle in React and created such component:

```
import React from "react";
import {useGetRemoteData} from "./useGetRemoteData";

export const SingleResponsibilityPrinciple = () => {

    const {filteredUsers , isLoading} = useGetRemoteData()

    const showDetails = (userId) => {
        const user = filteredUsers.find(user => user.id===userId);
        alert(user.contact)
    }

    return <>
        <div> Users List</div>
        <div> Loading state: {isLoading? 'Loading': 'Success'}</div>
        {filteredUsers.map(user => {
            return <div key={user.id} onClick={() => showDetails(user.id)}>
                <div>{user.name}</div>
                <div>{user.email}</div>
            </div>
        })}
    </>
}
```

As you can see above, I have this code

> const user = filteredUsers.find(user => user.id===userId);

The question is Is it best practice that if whenever we use map, reduce or any array function in React component, we should extract that logic out of a component, that is, `filteredUsers.find(user => user.id===userId);` should be extracted and we need to create utility function. So, function should not care about how a particular thing is done. Is it true?

Comment: In this particular case there is no need to lookup the user from the array because you already have access to the complete user object at the point where you are looping through.  You could just as well write onClick={() => alert(user.contact)} so you don’t need the showDetails function at all.

Comment: Don't mistake a good rule of thumb like SRP for being an inviolable law of the universe. A lot of blood, sweat, and tears have been spilt by slavishly following heuristics without applying critical thinking. That being said, I agree with @LindaPaiste a lot of this is superfluous so I'm not really sure what you're asking here.

Comment: @LindaPaiste, yeah my mistake : ) , but, overall,  whenever we use, say, map, reduce or find thanks to which we process certain data, should we extract the logic out of a component?

Comment: Personally I would move it outside the component if I thought I might use the same logic elsewhere.  It would be excessive to say that **every** array loop should go outside the component.  An array function isn’t really a “responsibility”.  I think of a responsibility as “load a list of users”, “display a list of users”, “display a user’s details”.  In that regard, it’s the visual displaying of the details (which right now is just an alert) that calls for a separate component or hook.  Not the lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question. I want to advice as follows

- It is better for your to check if **filteredUsers** exists or not in your *return*.

```
{filteredUsers?.map(user=>{
//your code
})
```

- You don't need to get specific user as you already loop in your map method. Just simply do something like this

```
{filteredUsers.map(user => {
            return <div key={user.id} onClick={() => showDetails(alert(user.contact))}>
                <div>{user.name}</div>
                <div>{user.email}</div>
            </div>
        })}
```

- Remember the difference between *find*, *filter* method of Javascript array. If you have unique value according to userId, you simply use *find* method to get the first value not array, if you use *filter*, you get arrays of the condition. Are you sure you don't need to **alert(user[0].contact)**, not **alert(user.contact)**?